# Передать _POST из View в model

Tags: php, post, mvc, model

Здравствуйте, помошники. Опять нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.Проблема в следующем:

Как передать данные из POST в Model?

Опишу подробнее. Делаю CRM для контроля часов работы(fat free framework).

На странице выводятся данные по всем отработанным часам, есть форма состоящая из button и input type=date. нужно передать дату из формы в model .

Кода много, скидывать не буду только скажу , что функция находится в модели и она берет из бд всех юзеров => все проекты по юзерам => задачи по юзерам и проектам
во второй этап нужно засунуть дату чтобы они фильтровались

PS  Желательно не AJAX пусть страница перезагружается

PSS Есть предчувствие ,что очень плохо описал проект и проблему и нечего не понятно . Спросите постараюсь ответить

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` - это так называемая [*суперглобальная переменная*](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.superglobals.php). К ней можно получить доступ из любого скрипта. Так что, отправив форму методом POST, вы спокойно можете обратиться к данным формы в модели через `$_POST['name']`.